# How to download stock time series for multiple companies in Eikon?

Tags: historical-data

I want to download several historical stock price histories from Eikon at once.
This is the stock data of several hundred companies. Therefore, it is far too time-consuming for me to download them all manually.
Does anyone have an idea how I could do this relatively quickly?
I have already downloaded an Excel spreadsheet with all relevant information. It also contains the RIC (Reuters Instrument Code) for the respective companies:
[image]
Using this code, I would like to download the corresponding stock price data for each company from Eikon.
Is this possible with the Excell add-on?
Or is there another way?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Eikon has an extensive catalog of APIs (Excel included).  You should read through their API documentation for exact instructions -- I believe they even have video tutorials that guide you through it.